# Type Error: Network Request Failed while uploading images from react native to firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to upload an image from my react native app to firebase but I am facing this error for 2 days and I am not getting the reason, I have done this thing before as well but this time this issue is araising. 
Here is my code,

```
_pickImageFront = async () => {
          let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            base64:true,
            quality:1.0
          });

          if(!pickerResult.cancelled){
            //this.setState({userImage: pickerResult.uri, imageResult : pickerResult, imageSelected: true});
            this.uploadImage(pickerResult.uri,'front-image')
            .then(()=>{
                alert('success');
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                alert(error)
            });
        }
      }

 uploadImage = async(uri,imageName) => {

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob =await response.blob();

    var ref = fire.storage().ref().child('images/'+imageName);
    return ref.put(blob);
}

//render method is here
                   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._pickImageFront}>

                        <Image
                        source={ImageIcon}
                        style={{width:wp('10%'),
                        height:hp('5%')}}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: It's really sad when your no one answers your question. Do you have any update on this ?